# Passar parâmetro no FILTER de um array em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sintaxe, filter

Preciso passar um parâmetro para uma função externa que quero criar para um `filter` de array, mas não sei como fazer. Exemplo: Esse código já funciona:

```
const myArray = [
    { "name": "nome1" },
    { "name": "nome2" },
    { "name": "nome3" },
    { "name": "nome4" },
    { "name": "nome5" }
];

let qParam = myRequest.query.myParam;

// Retorna o item do array cujo campo "name" corresponde a "qParam"
const user = myArray.filter(u => qParam === u.name)[0];
```

Agora quero fazer algo parecido com isso abaixo, mas não funciona, pois não consigo passar `qParam` por parâmetro e esta variável também está fora do escopo acessível por `myFunction`. Como resolvo isso:

```
function myFunction(value, qParam) {
    return value === qParam;
}
const user = myArray.filter(myFunction);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é utilizar o conceito de decorador, que de forma simplista é uma função que retorna outra função, aplicando algum tratamento sobre esta. Neste caso, o decorador receberia o parâmetro `name` e retornaria uma função que efetua o filtro do nome em relação ao valor de `name`:

```
function filterByName(name) {
  return function filter(value) {
      return value.name === name;
  }
}
```

Ou seja, para gerar um filtro que utilize como referência o valor de `qParam`, basta fazer:

```
const user = myArray.filter( filterByName(qParam) )[0];
```

Veja o exemplo:

```js
const myArray = [
    { "name": "nome1" },
    { "name": "nome2" },
    { "name": "nome3" },
    { "name": "nome4" },
    { "name": "nome5" }
];

let qParam = "nome3";

function filterByName(name) {
  return function filter(value) {
      return value.name === name;
  }
}

const user = myArray.filter(filterByName(qParam))[0];

console.log(user);
```

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado! Estou usando este código em Node.js e tentei escrever as funções no formato "arrow function", mas não funcionou não... será que não dá certo nem para a função interna, a  `filter` dentro da `filterByName`?

Comment: Não sei dizer com certeza. Acusou algum erro?

Comment: retorna undefined... como arrow function simplesmente não é reconhecido. Pelo menos da forma como eu escrevi.

Comment: @wBB Eu testei no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/IS1l/0) e funcionou perfeitamente. Confira se colocou com a sintaxe correta.

Comment: Essa que eu mandei no link no último comentário. Você viu?

Comment: Desculpe Anderson... eu não tinha percebido que você colocou o link associado a sua resposta e nem deu tempo de eu excluir meu comentário, pois você já postou outra resposta. Tá rápido demais no gatilho! Mas funcionou OK sua solução. Eu estava certo de que a função `filterByName` tinha que ter seu nome explicitado por ser externa (sem ser arrow), então fiz apenas a função interna como arrow function e por isso estava dando errado. Obrigado!